# log4j 2 - share filter between appenders without copy&paste

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Hello is it possible to have same filter for 2 appenders in log4j 2? Note I do not want it for all appenders.

Actually what I want to do is:
- to share filter for appenders: console and file.log
- and then have appender file.log_all which will log everything

I know I can just copy and paste the filter configuration but I would prefer to just use something like "FilterRef".

I also know I can set filter to logger but that is also not what I want as I have multiple loggers.